# how to debug the git feature "insteadof"

Tags: git, git-clone, git-config

the feature "Insteadof"  (mapping HTTPS to SSH) clone requests works when I directly clone a REPO

This is done via my global git config file.

- Put another way, "git clone https://url_module_K" works.
- My global git config transforms this into a SSH request.

HOWEVER -

If I git clone another module recursively which includes module_K as a sub-module it fails ...

ie:  git clone --recursive https://url_module_A

- The top level module "A" is transformed into an SSH request
- Works for Modules A, B, C, D, E ... all are transformed
- But - when it gets to Module K - it reverts to https and wants my username and password.

It is NOT a git ssh problem

it is sort of a problem with the "insteadof" mapping not working sometimes.

Is there a debug method for this to help me figure out what is causing this?

The remote server is bitbucket - with private repos.

Knowns:

- While I am mapping http to ssh via insteadof - this works for multiple other repos.
- I've looked - I do not see any insteadof things in any of the REPOs private(?local) config files
- I've already tried the "cut/paste" same URL so that I don't make stupid typos... that's not helping.

Unknowns:

- How do I trace the GIT activity... as it reads the config file. Suggestions?
- I've tried things like 'strace' to see if something is being passed on the command line somewhere - but - I think GIT is very security aware and does not do this sort of stuff on the command line -  -
- Also tried - "ps -auxwwf" while this is occuring is not helping determining the command line between various sub-components of git.
- And searching "git insteadof" - gets "fixed" by the Google Monster - and becomes "instead of" with spaces - even if I put the word in quotes... Thus having a hard time searching for things.

Comment: A google search for `git "insteadof"` seems to work just fine for me, without rewriting the search terms.

Comment: Sorry - that is not my question, I want to turn on some level of debug or verbose operation when performing a recursive git clone, there is a problem with a repo that should be converted from https to ssh - that's not happening correctly for some repos in some situations.

Comment: I realize that wasn't your question; that's why that was a comment, not an answer. However, your question indicates that you were having problem finding information because google was rewriting your queries, but that does not actually seem to be the case.  Perhaps a properly formatted search will help locate the information you are trying to find.

Comment: Sadly - It seems I need to learn "go" so that I can add debug log messages to figure out why this thing is not transforming the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this of use to anyone but you can get a quite verbose output by prefixing your `git` commands with `GIT_TRACE=1` and/or `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"`

For example, instead of running `git fetch`, try running...

```
GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git fetch
```

More details available here...
https://git-scm.com/docs/git